# XAML Heartbeat Animation - How to ensure heart beats at least twice

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm-light

Greetings,

I would like to visually show when a background process is working. This process happens at a regular intervals (say every 30 seconds), and might take 10ms or 1000ms+ to complete. I'm using MVVM-Light framework so have created a data trigger wired up to a view model property on an image of a heart fading in and out.

My amateur animation technique is working when the process takes a second or more, but I would also like it to complete a full heartbeat (2 repeats) when the process takes a short period of time (<100ms), otherwise the animation is over too quickly and you can't (visually) tell that the process is working.

The problem is that the heart should remain beating for the duration of the process, so I can't just set the repeat behaviour to 2. A XAML solution is preferred, but I will not cringe if some code behind is needed :)

```
<Image 
    Height="60" Width="60" Margin="0,6,6,6"
    Name="Heartbeat" Source="/Resources/Heartbeat.png"
    VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
    Opacity=".05" Stretch="UniformToFill">
    <Image.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsHeartBeating}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard Name="HeartbeatStoryboard">
                            <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                <DoubleAnimation
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                    From="0.05" To="0.8" Duration="0:0:0.100">
                                </DoubleAnimation>
                                <DoubleAnimation
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                    From="0.8" To="0.05" Duration="0:0:0.300">
                                    <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                        <PowerEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Power="6" />
                                    </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                </DoubleAnimation>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="HeartbeatStoryboard" />
                    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

And if anyone has any tips on how to improve the heartbeat animation, I'm open to suggestions, thanks!

Comment: @Si: I think you're gonna have to specify RepeatBehavior="2x" and subscribe to the Completed event for the StoryBoard and if IsHeartBeating is still true then you restart it. I'm not sure if you're using MVVM here so I'm unsure of how to start it for the first iteration

Comment: Thanks Meleak, that's a nice idea. Yes, I'm using MVVM-Light, but it will be easy enough to wire up the event in code behind and grab the view model from view data context. btw, please post this as an answer and I'll vote it up, cheers!

Comment: No joy I'm afraid Meleak, `The event 'Completed' cannot be specified on a Target tag in a Style. Use an EventSetter instead.` but it looks like Storyboard.Completed event is not a RoutedEvent, so event setter won't work either :)

Comment: @Si: That's what I noticed to so I made a Resouce of the Storyboard. From there the Completed event could be added, but then their was the problem with TargetName depending on if the Storyboard was started from the Style or not. I'll post an answer if I can work it out :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're gonna have to specify RepeatBehavior="2x" and subscribe to the Completed event for the StoryBoard and if IsHeartBeating is still true then you restart it.

```
<Image Height="60" Width="60" Margin="0,6,6,6"   
       Name="Heartbeat" Source="/Resources/Heartbeat.png"   
       VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right"    
       Opacity=".05" Stretch="UniformToFill">
    <Image.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="HeartbeatStoryboard2x"
                    RepeatBehavior="2x"
                    Completed="Storyboard_Completed">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                             Storyboard.Target="{Binding ElementName=Heartbeat}"
                             From="0.05" To="0.8" Duration="0:0:0.500">
            </DoubleAnimation>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                             Storyboard.Target="{Binding ElementName=Heartbeat}"
                             From="0.8" To="0.05" Duration="0:0:1.500">
                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                    <PowerEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Power="6" />
                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
            </DoubleAnimation>
        </Storyboard>
    </Image.Resources>
    <Image.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsHeartBeating}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard Name="HeartbeatStoryboard">
                            <StaticResource ResourceKey="HeartbeatStoryboard2x"/>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

Code behind event handler.
**Update**
Added boolean flag to only Stop the Storyboard when is has been re-started

```
private bool m_restartedAnimation = false;
private void Storyboard_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClockGroup clockGroup = sender as ClockGroup;
    Storyboard heartbeatStoryboard = clockGroup.Timeline as Storyboard;
    if (IsHeartBeating == true)
    {
        m_restartedAnimation = true;
        heartbeatStoryboard.Begin();
    }
    else
    {
        if (m_restartedAnimation == true)
        {
            heartbeatStoryboard.Stop();
        }
        m_restartedAnimation = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Working as expected. FWIW I am noticing a warning in the trace output, `Warning: 6 : Unable to perform action because the specified Storyboard was never applied to this object for interactive control.; Action='Stop'` but it's working and I'll have a look tomorrow after some rest (too many late night hacking sessions this week:)

Comment: @Si: You're right, the warning appears when Stop is executed for the animation that's started from the DataTrigger (no re-start). I can't find a way to tell the difference and the warning is probably harmless but a simple true false flag should get rid of it.